# Standard topology distance function

Tags: general-topology

I am reading the paper "Measure and Integration" by Dietmar A. Salamon, ETH Zürich.

it starts out quite normal, defining normed vector spaces, topologies.

Then the author choses to throw in an exercise that goes like:

Exercise 1.13. Consider the set

$\overline{\mathbb{R}} := [-\infty,\infty] = \mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$

for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ define

$(a, \infty] := (a, \infty) \cup \{\infty\}, [-\infty, b) := (-\infty, b)\cup \{-\infty\}$

Call a subset $U\subset \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ **open** if it is a countable union of open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ and sets of the form $(a, \infty$] or $(-\infty, b]$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$

(i) Show that the set of open subsets of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ satisifes the axioms of a topology. This is called the **standard topology** on $\mathbb{R}$

(ii) Prove that the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is induced by the distance function $d: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined by the following formulas for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$:

$d(x, y) := \frac{2|e^{x-y} - e^{y-x}|}{e^{x+y}+e^{x-y}+e^{y-x}+e^{-x-y}}$

$d(x,\infty) := d(\infty,x) := \frac{2e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}$

$d(x,-\infty) := d(-\infty,x) := \frac{2e^{x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}$

$d(-\infty,\infty) := d(\infty,-\infty) := 2$.

I am afraid i do not see the reasoning behind the statement in (ii) at all even less how to prove it. It is way beyond what I know so far regarding distance functions in metrics spaces $L^p$.

I would be very happy if someone could help me shed some light on the proof for (ii)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x)=\tanh x,$ where $\sinh x=(e^x-e^{-x})/2$ and $\cosh x=(e^x+e^{-x})/2$ and $\tanh x =\frac {\sinh x }{ \cosh x}.$

$f:\mathbb R\to (-1,1)$ is a continuous strictly monotonic surjection, hence it is a homeomorphism. So we may take the usual metric $e(u,v)=|u-v|$ on $(-1,1),$ and define a metric $d$ on $\mathbb R$ by $$d(x,y)=e(f(x),f(y))=|\tanh x -\tanh y|.$$
 Then $d$ generates the usual topology on $\mathbb R$ because $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Take the metric completion of $(-1,1),$ which is $[-1,1]$ with its usual metric.  Since $(\mathbb R,d)$ is isomorphic to $((-1,1),e),$  this induces a metric completion on $(\mathbb R,d)$ which adds 2 points called $\pm \infty,$ (corresponding to the points $\pm 1$ added to $(-1,1)\;$) with $d(\pm \infty,x)=e((\pm 1),\tanh x)=|(\pm 1)-\tanh x|$ for $x\in \mathbb R,$ and $d(-\infty,\infty)=e(-1,1)=2.$